# Django Query: Group/Count orders by foreign key of foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a hard time wrapping my head around how to achieve this. I have 3 fairly simple models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Seller(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    order         = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    seller        = models.ForeignKey(Seller, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    order_date    = models.DateField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

"**Orders**" are simple product orders placed by "**Sellers**" are the businesses we supply and "**Country**" defines in which country these sellers are based. It could be the case that in country we have many sellers and that in the next country we only have 1.

A simplified description of the orders for better understanding of my question:

```
Order N° 1 by seller A from Germany
Order N° 2 by seller B from Germany
Order N° 3 by seller C from France
Order N° 4 by seller D from Spain
Order N° 5 by seller F from France
```

What I would like to achieve is to group all orders from countries that exist in that Model. E.g.: (

```
Country  | Count of all orders by country
{Germany :      7 
Spain    :      12
France   :      5}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
Order.objects.filter(customer__country__name__contains='Germany').annotate(count = Count('customer')).count()
```

It kinda works, but I would have to manually create as many queries as there are countries. Is there a possibility to loop over all countries and extract this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use group by here(according to the models in the question):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Order.objects.values('seller__country__name').annotate(count=Count('seller')).values('seller__country__name','count')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply wrap you country. Like this

```
for country in Country.objects.all():
    contains = {'customer__country__name__contains': country.name}
    Order.objects.filter(**contains).annotate(count = Count('customer')).count()
```

Comment: It worked, too! But Ruddra's approach is a bit more straightforward. Nonetheless, thank you very much!